# Android WebRTC crashes with intel webRTC suite

Tags: android, webrtc

I am using an intel webRTC library. https://software.intel.com/en-us/webrtc-sdk/

It only crashes on a particular phone however..

```
E/rtc: #

# Fatal error in ../../webrtc/api/java/jni/androidnetworkmonitor_jni.cc, line 195

# Check failed: !jni()->ExceptionCheck()

# Error during CallVoidMethod
```

I see that my device got an SDP offer and sent it over. But it seems that it wasn't able to gather any ice candidates and crashed there.

LG G2 (LG-D800) running android 5.0.2. Build# LRX22G

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK nevermind. I was only looking at the error log. Looking at verbose level helps solve the issue..

```
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10188 nor current process has android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE.
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user W/System.err:     at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.requestNetwork(IConnectivityManager.java:2443)
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user W/System.err:     at android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3210)
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user W/System.err:     at android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3237)
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user W/System.err:     at org.webrtc.NetworkMonitorAutoDetect$ConnectivityManagerDelegate.requestMobileNetwork(NetworkMonitorAutoDetect.java:341)
01-15 12:28:55.127 10743-10743/? I/MusicBrowser: [MediaPlaybackService.java:2079:saveQueue()] oooooo {full=true}
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user W/System.err:     at org.webrtc.NetworkMonitorAutoDetect.<init>(NetworkMonitorAutoDetect.java:449)
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user W/System.err:     at org.webrtc.NetworkMonitor.setAutoDetectConnectivityStateInternal(NetworkMonitor.java:139)
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user W/System.err:     at org.webrtc.NetworkMonitor.startMonitoring(NetworkMonitor.java:108)
01-15 12:28:55.127 30077-31547/com.test.user E/rtc: #
                                                                 # Fatal error in ../../webrtc/api/java/jni/androidnetworkmonitor_jni.cc, line 195
                                                                 # Check failed: !jni()->ExceptionCheck()
                                                                 # Error during CallVoidMethod
                                                                 #
```